# Has there ever been a case of dangerous industrial malware, which would destroy motherboards and similar PC components and how to protect

Tags: malware, physical, detection

I heard many years ago from word of mouth that this kind of malware exists, which could for example blow up capacitors in your PC.

- Has such malware or something even remotely similar ever existed?
- How do you technically detect such malware (if it already exists)?
- How is it called?
- Isn't it kind of unrealistic to have such malware due to the different kinds of hardware in PCs/Servers/etc?

---

- If it's not fictional then how do the safeguards protect against such threats and what about the fact that the safeguards would have loopholes?

Comment: like this? https://www.kaspersky.co.uk/blog/fact-or-fiction-virus-damaging-hardware/6241/

Comment: I find this question strangely specific: its about damage against PC components in an industrial context. I would argue that especially in industrial context the damage against the PC is much less relevant than the damage against what it controls, i.e. malicious activity causing production loss, production anomalies or even safety problems. Example being the breakage of centrifuges done by [Stuxnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet).

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65153/is-there-any-virus-that-can-cause-physical-damage https://www.wired.com/2016/03/inside-cunning-unprecedented-hack-ukraines-power-grid/

Comment: Stuxnet attacked controllers and not general-purpose PCs afaik, please do correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Stuxnet was designed to destroy hardware, but not PC components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Software-based malware can conceivably damage/wear down your hard drive/SSD by overusing it and overwriting it repetitively.
You could, in the past, also seriously mess up your CPU/GPU configuration by playing with Windows registry keys (overclocking and such), so that is/was also a possible vector.

Firmware based attacks (BIOS malware/bootkits) in general can have impacts on hardware, as can physical attacks (ie [Killer USBs](https://usbkill.com/)).

The "industrial" malware you may be thinking of is [Stuxnet](https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/security-awareness/ransomware/what-is-stuxnet.html), an attack on PLCs in Iranian nuclear facilities.

Attackers tend to have specific targets (and/or go after protocols that are widely used) with attacks like this, so portability is not a concern.

Companies protect against insidious hardware-based malware the same way they do against other malware: strict configuration and policies to make it difficult for attackers. Detection is difficult if the malware is written well, but it could be mitigated by regular benchmarks and checking of health of hardware.

Comment: I'm guessing firmware based attacks all always not effective against that specific product and firmware version, is that correct?

Comment: @SirMuffington If you mean they leverage a more random/brute-force method and are not always effective on the first try, sure, but why wouldn't they be effective on any machines matching target specs, given it was developed for a specific hardware setup and firmware version? There's not much "hardening" configuration you can do on firmware usually, and companies tend to leave the manufacturers' flashed ROM alone.